# Sum Items from Multiple Tables in SQL

Tags: sql

I have two tables, one with a list of sales, and another with the product definitions. What I'm trying to do is calculate the total revenue for each product. In the sales table, there are multiple instances of a single product, so what I need to do is sum the quantity sold for each product type and multiply that by the price.

Here is a sample table to better explain:

**Sales**

```
name | qty | sid
-----+-----+------
p1   |  2  | 1
p2   |  3  | 2 
p1   |  5  | 1 
p3   |  1  | 3
```

**products**

```
name | price | pid
-----+-------+----- 
p1   | 2.99  | 1
p2   | 5.00  | 2
p3   | 4.25  | 3
```

This is my attempt at solving this problem:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(product.name) AS product_name, 
    COUNT(sales.sid) AS Count_sales
FROM 
    products 
LEFT JOIN 
    sales ON sales.sid = products.pid
GROUP BY 
    products.pid;
```

I've successfully been able to count the instances of each product in the sales list. However, I can't figure out how to also account for the quantity column as well as multiplying that by the price of each product.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a `SUM` function in sql you should probably be using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want:

```
SELECT MAX(p.name) AS product_name, SUM(p.price * s.sid) AS total_price
FROM products p LEFT JOIN
     sales s
     ON s.sid = p.pid
GROUP BY p.pid;
```